# Map incoming JSON

Tags: arrays, json

I have this incoming json response

```
      "orders": [
        {
          "items": ["Mie goreng", "Ayam bakar"],
          "qty": ["2", "1"],
          "order_time": "17:30"
        },
      ]
```

I want to map it into this:

```
      "orders": [
        {
          "items": [
              {item: "Mie goreng", qty: "2"},
              {item: "Ayam bakar", qty: "1"},
          ],
          "order_time": "17:30"
        },
      ]
```

Basically I want to map item and quantity into array object

Comment: Try something.....

Comment: super generic question, look at some basics here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) Could you format your code and provide your attempts? We can help you debugging it if it doesn't behave as you expect. Maybe providing the expected output could help too?

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me! this my first time, I tried edit and format the json code by surrounding between backtick as in instruction but the system keep saying "It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details"

Comment: reformatted for you to just include the relevant bits. this is most likely better solved by updating whatever is populating this data rather than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map on the `orders` array, then within those iterations, map on the `items` array. `Array#map` takes the iterated index as a second parameter, which can help finding the quantity of the iterated item. For instance, something like:

```js
const input = {
  "orders": [
    {
      "items": ["Mie goreng", "Ayam bakar"],
      "qty": ["2", "1"],
      "order_time": "17:30"
    },
  ]
};

const output = {
  orders: input.orders.map((order) => ({
    items: order.items.map((item, index) => ({
      item,
      qty: order.qty[index]
    })),
    order_time: order.order_time
  }))
};
```